# Got stuck while integrating $\int x^x dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, exponentiation

What is the integration of $$\int x^x dx$$ And how can I understand whether an integration is possible or not? Is there any rule to understand whether a function is integrable or not?

Comment: WA shows that there is no integral in terms of standard elementary functions.

Comment: this question was asked hundreds of times before. use the search function properly next time!

Comment: That is a duplicate only for the first question, and not the other two.  For help on understanding when an integral can be done in finite terms, I like this introductory paper: Rosenlicht, Maxwell,
Integration in finite terms. 
*Amer. Math. Monthly* 79 (1972), 963–972.

Comment: @ user103379 : This paper may give you some clue :  https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function